# Null cast in Android RecyclerView won't go away even if I don't do any cast at all

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm having a very strange null cast error on my `RecyclerView`. The code that gives the error is shown below, but I also provide the entire code [here](https://pastebin.com/D92WRekL)

```
private val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
        ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT or ItemTouchHelper.LEFT
    ) {

        var dragFrom = -1
        var dragTo = -1
        override fun onMove(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ): Boolean {

            val fromPos = viewHolder.adapterPosition
            val toPos = target.adapterPosition
            if (dragFrom == -1) {
                dragFrom = fromPos
            }
            dragTo = toPos
            effectList.add(toPos, effectList.removeAt(fromPos))
            recyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemMoved(fromPos, toPos)
            return true
        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onswiped!");

            val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
            effectList.removeAt(position)
            mRecyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemRemoved(position)
            NativeInterface.removeEffectAt(position)

            for (i in position until effectList.size) {
                var holder = mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i) as? EffectsHolder
                holder?.bindEffect(holder.effect, i)
            }


        }

        override fun clearView(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ) {
            super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder)
            if (dragFrom != -1 && dragTo != -1 && dragFrom != dragTo) {
                rotateItems(dragFrom, dragTo)
            }
            dragFrom = -1
            dragTo = -1
        }

        override fun isLongPressDragEnabled(): Boolean = false
        override fun isItemViewSwipeEnabled(): Boolean = false

        fun rotateItems(fromPos: Int, toPos: Int) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onrotate!!");
            val a = min(fromPos, toPos)
            val b = max(fromPos, toPos)
            for (i in a..b) {
                var holder = mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i) as? EffectsHolder
                holder?.bindEffect(holder.effect, i)
            }
            NativeInterface.rotateEffectAt(fromPos, toPos)
        }
    })
```

The error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.stompai.kick, PID: 20883
    kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.mobileer.androidfxlab.EffectsAdapter.EffectsHolder
        at com.mobileer.androidfxlab.EffectsAdapter$itemTouchHelper$1.onSwiped(EffectsAdapter.kt:213)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper$4.run(ItemTouchHelper.java:712)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6617)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
```

You can see by the error message that it happens in the `itemTouchHelper.onSwiped`. You can see that I **did do a safe cast** to an `EffectsHolder`! It still gives the error! I then completely commented the function:

```
override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onswiped!");
            /*
            val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
            effectList.removeAt(position)
            mRecyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemRemoved(position)
            NativeInterface.removeEffectAt(position)

            for (i in position until effectList.size) {
                var holder = mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i) as? EffectsHolder
                holder?.bindEffect(holder.effect, i)
            }

            */
        }
```

But it still gives the same error! The error blames line **213** which is not onSwiped but it's where th eitemTouchHelper finishes. I guess the compiles it not able to detect exactly but it says onSwiped on the backtrace as you can see.

How is it possible that it blames a null cast conversion if I'm not casting anything??

Comment: I'd guess you are running an older version of the code and not the one you think you are. It would explain the error and the wrong stack trace. You should trust more the compiler ;)

Comment: Clean Project and build again should work. You can also disable "Instant Run".